SQLITE - getting error 21 when using sqlite3_prepare_v2()
SQLITE3 library returns error 21 (SQLITE_MISUSE) when I call sqlite3_prepare_v2()
https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#misuse
Here's my (very trivial code).
The statement I want to execute is:
CREATE TABLE 'T_COMPANY' ('ID' INTEGER NOT NULL,'NAME' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('ID' AUTOINCREMENT))
The query is composed correctly by the upper code as the log I produce confirms:
- SQLITE prepare statement error.
- Error code: 21
- Statement:
 CREATE TABLE 'T_COMPANY' ('ID' INTEGER NOT NULL,'NAME' TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('ID' AUTOINCREMENT))
- Address: (nil)


static int sqlInitDatabase(sqlite3 *pDb, const char *dbfile)
{
    int rc;

    if(SQLITE_OK != (rc = sqlite3_initialize())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "- Error initializing SQLITE engine. Error code: %d\n Aborting.\n", rc);
        return rc;
    }

    if(SQLITE_OK != (rc = sqlite3_open_v2(dbfile, &pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "- Fail to load or create DB file %s.\n- Error code: %d\n Aborting.\n", dbfile, rc);
        return rc;
    }

    return rc;
}

static void sqlCloseDatabase(sqlite3 *pDb)
{
    if(pDb != NULL) {
        sqlite3_close(pDb);
        sqlite3_shutdown();
    }
}

int sqlDeployDatabase(char *name)
{
    sqlite3 *pDb;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *query;
    int rc;
    
    if(name == NULL || strcmp(name, "") == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "- Database name cannot be empty.\n- Aborting\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(SQLITE_OK != (rc = sqlInitDatabase(pDb, name))) {
        return rc;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= NUM_TABLES; i++) {
        if(!(query = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * SQL_STMT_BUF))) {
            sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for building the query. Aborting.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        memset(query, 0, SQL_STMT_BUF);

        buildCreateStmt(tables, i, query, 0);
        
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, query, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "- SQLITE prepare statement error.\n- Error code: %d\n- Statement:\n %s\n- Address: %p\n", rc, query, stmt);
            free(query);
            sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
            return rc;
        }

        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "- SQLITE step error.\n- Error code: %d\n- Statement:\n %\ns", rc, query);
            free(query);
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
            return rc;
        }

        free(query);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }

    sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
}

Searching through the internet doesn't help.
Any suggestion on this?
TY

for(int i = 0; i <= NUM_TABLES; i++) {-> I think you mean for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TABLES; i++) {, remember arrays are 0 based in C.

Sure, however, it blocks at the first round...

Change to CREATE TABLE 'T_COMPANY' ('ID' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY, 'NAME' TEXT NOT NULL) ID is already an alias for rowid and the separate PRIMARY KEY should only be used for multiple columns.

I found the error: static int sqlInitDatabase(sqlite3 *pDb, const char *dbfile) must have a double pointer as the first parameter, otherwise sqlite3_open_v2() doesn't update the caller. It solved now. The queries are perfect.

I found the error: static int sqlInitDatabase(sqlite3 *pDb, const char *dbfile) must have a double pointer as first parameter, otherwise sqlite3_open_v2() doesn't update the caller. It's solved now. Queries are perfect.
static int sqlInitDatabase(sqlite3 **pDb, const char *dbfile)
{
    int rc;
    
    if(SQLITE_OK != (rc = sqlite3_initialize())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "- Error initializing SQLITE engine. Error code: %d\n Aborting.\n", rc);
        return rc;
    }
    
    if(SQLITE_OK != (rc = sqlite3_open_v2(dbfile, pDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "- Fail to load or create DB file %s.\n- Error code: %d\n Aborting.\n", dbfile, rc);
        return rc;
    }
    
    return SQLITE_OK;
}



static void sqlCloseDatabase(sqlite3 *pDb)
{
    if(pDb != NULL) {
        sqlite3_close(pDb);
        sqlite3_shutdown();
    }
}

int sqlDeployDatabase(char *name)
{
    sqlite3 *pDb;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *query;
    int rc;
    
    if(name == NULL || strcmp(name, "") == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "- Database name cannot be empty.\n- Aborting\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(SQLITE_OK != (rc = sqlInitDatabase(&pDb, name))) {
        return rc;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TABLES; i++) {
        if(!(query = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * SQL_STMT_BUF))) {
            sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for building the query. Aborting.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        memset(query, 0, SQL_STMT_BUF);

        buildCreateStmt(tables, i, query, 1);
        
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, query, strlen(query) + 1, &stmt, NULL);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "- SQLITE prepare statement error.\n- Error code: %d\n- Statement:\n %s\n- Address: %p\n", rc, query, stmt);
            free(query);
            sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
            return rc;
        }
        
        fprintf(stderr, "Query num %d: %s\n\n", i, query );
        
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "- SQLITE step error.\n- Error code: %d\n- Statement:\n %s\n", rc, query);
            free(query);
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
            return rc;
        }
        
        fprintf(stderr, "Return code: %d\n\n", rc);

        free(query);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }

    sqlCloseDatabase(pDb);
}

